# Modiying MSI in Orca

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, orca

I have a project which has the sqlite dll's (32 bit and 64 bit). The MSI is created from Visual Studio 2010, the problem is that VS detects the presence of 64 bit dll and since its targetted to x86 platform,VS gives an error saying it cannot copy the 64 bit dll, since its targetted to x86. When I change the platform to x64,it works fine but the MSI will obviously not work on x86 machines. I don't want to create 2 MSI's. I know that ORCA can be used to modify the MSI and also all my projects in the solution are targetted to Any Cpu. The only problem lies in the MSI. Can anyone explain how I modify the MSI using Orca to make it work on x86 as well?

Comment: If it's not possible with Orca then perhaps you could rename the DLL when you're packaging it, and then rename it with a custom action after it has been copied to the target machine?

Answer (score 0):

I actually decompressed my dll using deflatestream class in .net and inflate it back to normal on client side.That works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

MSI can deploy to both x64 and x86 locations. This really depends on component attribute. If you place dll into component which have attribute 256 than it goes to 64bit location. you may want to add 8 to that. Please, see details on component attributes here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx